# findOneAndUpdate Mongoose w/ PUT REST API

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my first attempt at this, it's very simple, I just want to find all documents with provided parameter (box: "Box 1") and of those find all the documents with the provided property (supplies: "Cleaning"). Then update all of those documents from box: "Box 1" to box: "Box 2". The result would be all cleaning supplies are now moved to Box 2. So a document would go from {box: "Box 1", supplies: "Cleaning"} to {box: "Box 2", supplies: "Cleaning"}

**Error**

```
"Cannot PUT /updatebox/Box%201/Cleaning" //in Postman
"404 Not Found" //in Postman log
```

**Schema & Model**

```
var boxSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    box: String,
    supplies: String
});

var boxModel = mongoose.model('boxModel', boxSchema, 'boxList');
```

**API**

```
app.put('updatebox/:box/:supplies', function (req, res) {
    var boxReq = req.params.box;
    var suppliesReq = req.params.supplies;
    boxModel
        .find({box: boxReq})
        .findOneAndUpdate({supplies: suppliesReq}, {
            $set: {
                box: "Box 2"
            }
        }, {new: true}, function (err, doc) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Something wrong when updating data!");
            }
            res.json(doc);
        });
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the preceding '/' before the actual route

This line in your API

`app.put('updatebox/:box/:supplies', function (req, res) {`

Should really be

`app.put('/updatebox/:box/:supplies', function (req, res) {`

Comment: Ah I should know better, I keep doing that! Thank you!

Comment: @muninn9 np, if this was the answer, please mark it as such so future visitors to this question will know that this actually solved your problem

Comment: No problem, I had to wait 4 minutes before accepting the answer :)